# How can I make my ftp directory writable for wordpress plugin update?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, error-handling, permissions, updates

I try to update a plugin in wordpress. 
When I press on "update" they ask me for my ftp settings.
Then the Plugin tries to update and I get the error

> Update failed: Directory could not be created.

I changed the folder permissions on 770 recursive for the plugins folder. But still not working.

Comment: Try changing its permissions to `755` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if this happens I like to reset all the file/folder permissions on the site https://gist.github.com/Adirael/3383404 is a sh file that will do this, if you dont have ssh access a lot of dashboards will have a reset permissions utility that may do the trick.

Alternatlvy find out the FTP credentials for the site and complete the form this should work.

There are extensions that claim to be able to do this however I would advise not using them as the process is pretty simple and they may introduce other issues especially as from the sounds of it you wouldnt be able to install the extensions.